# Symfony Form not rendering

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

A simple form is not rendering, it throws an error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance
>   of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, none given, called in
>   C:\Development\Projects\ShopStock\var\cache\dev\twig\14\144a2b61bf8b4b2e2549f7da9c9acb553cbf793088729905b2adf9cd03dbe799.php
>   on line 103

---

ProductForm.php:

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

/**
 * Product Form
 */
class ProductForm extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add("ean", TextType::class, array(
            "label" => "product.ean"
        ));

        $builder->add("name", TextType::class, array(
            "label" => "product.name"
        ));
    }
}
```

ProductController.php:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Form\ProductForm;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

/**
 * Product Controller
 */
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface
     */
    private $_translator;

    /**
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->_translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * Edit
     *
     * @ParamConverter("product", class="App\Entity\Product")
     * @Route("product/{slug}/edit", name = "product-edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     * @Template(template = "product/product_edit.html.twig")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Product $product
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $form = $this->createEditProductForm($product);

        // check for POST request
        if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            // check validation
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // ....
            }
        }

        return array(
            "form"      => $form->createView(),
            "product"   => $product
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create Edit Product Form
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @return FormInterface
     */
    private function createEditProductForm(Product $product)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductForm::class, $product, array(
            "action" => $this->generateUrl("product-edit", array("slug" => $product->getSlug())),
            "method" => Request::METHOD_POST
        ));

        $form->add("submit", SubmitType::class, array(
            "label" => $this->_translator->trans("save", array(), "form")
        ));

        return $form;
    }
}
```

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.0.8",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "portphp/csv": "^1.0",
    "portphp/doctrine": "^1.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
    "symfony/asset": "^3.4",
    "symfony/console": "^3.4",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^3.4",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/form": "^3.4",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/lts": "^3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "^3.4",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/translation": "^3.4",
    "symfony/validator": "^3.4",
    "symfony/web-link": "^3.4",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "*",
    "symfony/yaml": "^3.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^3.4",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^3.4",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^3.4",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.4",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
},
```

product_edit.html.twig

```
{% extends 'layout/base.layout.html.twig' %}

{# import relevant macros #}
{% import "macro/form_macro.html.twig" as form_macro %}

{# set translation domain #}
{% trans_default_domain 'product' %}

{% block title %}{{ "product.edit"|trans }} - {{ product.name }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<!-- Product Edit -->
{{ form_start(form) }}

{{ form_macro.form_input(form.ean) }}
{{ form_macro.form_input(form.name) }}

{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
{{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_end() }}
<!-- Product Edit End -->
{% endblock %}
```

form_macro.html.twig

```
{# @param field     the input field of the form     #}
{% macro form_input(field) %}
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        {{ form_label(field) }}
        {{ form_widget(field) }}
        {{ form_errors(field) }}
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

---

What I've tried so far:

- clearing the cache from the console (php bin/console cache:clear)
- deleting the cache directory ({project-root-dir}/var/cache)

I'm running a development environment from the build in web-server in the console (php bin/console server:run)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you provide the Twig view as well please?

Comment: just added them @nbonniot

Comment: What's in form_macro.html.twig? For testing purpose could you try to render your ean and name with classic form_widget or form_row ?

Comment: I did try that, it renders the same error on screen. also this macro has proved to work in previous applications

Comment: As another check, could you try to render empty form (comment or remove fields+token+submit). To find out where error is triggered. I cannot test it myself for now, but your code seems good to me AFAIS.

Comment: that also makes no difference :(

Comment: Could you provide complete form class (options resolver, custom build view if any...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **product_edit.html.twig**, you forgot to provide the **form** in **form_end**. Change:

```
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: a mistake like this is so easy overlooked, I'm glad you found it!